# Sitecore MVC view model inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I have two Sitecore templates - a `Base template` and a `Test template` which inherits from the `Base template`. The `Base template` contains a field called `title` and the `Test template` contains a field called `page description`.

I have a `Test Template` view model inheriting from the `Base template` view model (which implements `IRenderingModel`).

The `Base template` view model has this property:

```cs
public HtmlString RenderedTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Title"));
        }
    }
```

And the `Test Template` View Model has this property:

```cs
public HtmlString RenderedPageDescription
{
    get
    {
        return new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Page Description"));
    }
}
```

I also have my view outputting these two properties:

```cs
@Model.RenderedTitle
@Model.RenderedPageDescription
```

The Problem is that when I view the page in the page editor, only the `renderedPageDescription` property is editable. For whatever reason, the `RenderedTitle` property is not being set as editable. I tried throwing the `RenderedTitle` property into the `Test Template` View Model and it worked fine.

Does anyone have any ideas of why the `RenderedTitle` property is not editable when it's in the parent class?

Thanks in advance.

(I'm also using Sitecore 7.2)

Comment: From where is 'Item' property coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following line in the Initialize() method on your Test Template View Model?

base.Initialize(rendering);

i.e.

```
Public override void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
{
    base.Initialize(rendering)
}
```